# Custom order of CPT posts by title, in wp-admin area by default

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-admin, sort

Its tough to know/determine/see if a plugin is ever overriding or will override my ability to use  `$query->set('orderby', 'title')` when I am attempting to sort my admin posts by title, for my custom post type.

Instead, is there a way from my functions.php file that I can append orderby to my CPT "careers" link, so that it looks like this before the editor clicks on it...

`.../wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=careers&orderby=title&order=asc`

instead of its default look...

`.../wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=careers`

Comment: I changed my question because I am still stuck on this